# phpmailer error sending when upload file button isn't used in contact form

Tags: php, phpmailer, attachment

I am pretty sure this is fixable but I have just been through lots of posts and can't find the answer.

I have a contact form that has an upload button but this is optional.

If the upload button isn't used than the form returns an error.

The form bit:

`<input class="form-control" type="file" name="attachment">`

--

```
        if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] != "") {
        $file = "attachment/" . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $file);
    } else
        $file = "";
```

--

```
   $mail->addAttachment($file);
$mail->send();
```

I am wondering if there is a way to let the php know that the button if nothing needs to be uploaded then the button is 'false'

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably enough if you wrap `$mail->addAttachment($file);` into an `if ($file !== '') { ... }`

Comment: It will be great if you share the exception